How to achieve a git pull from a CGNAT?
I imagine my scenario to be reasonably common, so I am wondering if there is a method to achieve it.
I perform development on my local machine, which is either connected to the internet over my home Wi-Fi, or over my mobile 4G hotspot.
As I am currently working away from home my question is focused on the mobile 4G case.
I initialise a bare git repository on my local machine, to serve as a central backup from which I may pull/push edits.
If I wish to make edits locally, I can git clone the bare repo, issue pull requests, and once finished adding updates, can then git push origin to update the central repo.
The issue I have, is when I wish to add any new updates to a remote machine not on my local network.
How can I run git clone or git pull on my remote machine, to retrieve git info on my local machine ?
The problem arises due to the network set-up, which I have outlined in my solution attempts listed below.
Alternate method
If I host my centralised repo on the remote machine, I can make pull requests locally, perform edits, and push changes back to the remote. This does not achieve my aim of having a centralised backup on my local machine. Effectively, I want to achieve the same as this, but issuing pull requests on my remote machine, instead of pull requests on my local machine.
Attempts at a solution:

In trying to diagnose my network set-up I have found the following on my local machine:


My IP address according to: https://whatismyipaddress.com/ is different to that returned by hostname -I.
Running nmap -sT -p- $(hostname -I) locally, I am informed port 22 is listening for SSH requests, and port 80 is listening for HTTP requests. I assume this to only be true for requests within the local network.
Running nmap -sT -p- ${LOCALIP} on my remote machine, where ${LOCALIP} is my local IP as returned by https://whatismyipaddress.com/, returns a time-out error.
Issuing a PING from my remote machine to my local machines IP as returned by https://whatismyipaddress.com/, also returns a time-out error.


Based on the results of step (1), I conclude that my local machine has an IP within my local network, and this is returned by hostname -I. I assume similarly, I could connect another device to this network, and it would have a unique local IP - again, only accessible within the local network. The public IP returned by https://whatismyipaddress.com/, acts as a router, passing requests from my local machine to the internet, and returning the result. In my reading, I have seen mention of this possibly being a CGNAT setup.

How can I access my local machines ports - eg: over SSH, though ultimately to perform a git clone request - via the publicly visible IP as returned by https://whatismyipaddress.com/ ?
Extra info
My local and remote machines both run Ubuntu 20.04 with bash. My mobile network provider is Superdrug in the UK.
I originally posted this question on ServerFault, but as it is not business specific, I am posting here instead.

so to save a few hundred words, your question is how to host public services when your ISP uses CGNat, correct? The most common solution is to use reverse tunneling with a commercial Internet service like a VPN. Many VPNs will let you use one of their public IPs as your own. traffic to it is passed through a VPN connection you initiate from inside your network, so that your server can be reached.  https://silentbio.com/how-to-configure-a-vpn-with-port-forwarding/ There are risks though, so make sure you understand them before opening anything up.
